# Expected Value Contradiction

Tags: expected-value

I am stuck with a simple expected value problem. Here it is:
Assume I have 1 USD in savings now. I have to decide whether I keep my savings in USD or convert them into Euros. At the moment 1 USD = 1 Euro. I know that in one year, there is a (1) 50% chance that 1 USD would be equal to 0.80 Euros, and there is a (2) 50% chance that 1 USD would be equal to 1.25 Euros. So the expected value of 1 USD in one year is `0.80 * 0.5 + 1.25 * 0.5 = 1.025 Euros`. So that means I keep my savings in USD.
However, if I just had 1 Euro in my savings, with the same exchange rates, there would be a 50% chance that that 1 Euro would be equal to `1 / 0.80 = 1.25 USD` (case 1 above) and a 50% chance that 1 Euro would be worth `1 / 1.25 = 0.80 USD` (case 2 above). Therefore the expected value 1 Euro in one year in this case is `1.25 * 0.5 + 0.80 * 0.5 = 1.025 USD`. Therefore I should keep my savings in Euro.
These two statements cannot be true simultaneously. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't made a mistake, both options have a positive expected value. What you've found is that the expected value behaves a bit strangely when looking at multiplicative changes. The mathematical explanation is that

$$0.5x + 0.5\frac{1}{x} \geq 1, \forall x > 0$$

With equality exactly when $x = 1$.

Re-phrasing the problem might make it more intuitive. Consider gambling, and you're going to bet on a coin flip. The wager is \$10, you'll receive double your bet if you guess correctly and only half of it if you guess wrong. That is, if you bet correctly you will win \$20, if you guess wrong you'll only win \$5. Then expected value of betting on Heads is

$$ 0.5*\$5 + 0.5 * \$20 = \$ 12.50$$

By symmetry the expected value of betting on Tails is the same. So it doesn't matter which one you bet on, you expect to make a profit overall.